# AnyHashable as an alternative to AnyEquatable

Tags: swift, type-erasure

I need to compare arrays of structs that conform to a protocol `P`.

`P` can't conform to Equatable because it must not have "Self requirements".

Creating [`AnyEquatable`](https://gist.github.com/JadenGeller/f0d05a4699ddd477a2c1) as a type erasure is a common practice for this purpose.
However, `AnyHashable` is already part of the standard library and it conforms to `Equatable`.

I wonder if `AnyEquatable` is not part of the standard library for a good reason.
Should the standard `AnyHashable` be used instead of `AnyEquatable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AnyHashable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyhashable) wraps up a bunch of common functionality. That `AnyEquatable` doesn't; what it does can be represented with just a closure.

```swift
let cupcake = ""
let notCake = 0xca_e

let cupcakeEquals: (Any) -> Bool = try cupcake.getEquals()
XCTAssert( cupcakeEquals(cupcake) )
XCTAssertFalse( cupcakeEquals(notCake) )

let notCakeEquals = try notCake.getEquals(Any.self)
XCTAssert( notCakeEquals(notCake) )
XCTAssertFalse( notCakeEquals(cupcake) )

XCTAssertThrowsError( try cupcake.getEquals(Int.self) )
```

```swift
public extension Equatable {
  /// A closure that equates another instance to this intance.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - _: Use the metatype for `Castable` to avoid explicit typing.
  /// - Throws: `CastError.impossible` if a `Castable` can't be cast to `Self`.
  func getEquals<Castable>(_: Castable.Type = Castable.self) throws -> (Castable) -> Bool {
    if let error = CastError(self, desired: Castable.self)
    { throw error }

    return { self == $0 as? Self }
  }
}
```

```swift
/// An error that represents casting gone wrong. ‍♀️
public enum CastError: Error {
  /// An undesired cast is possible.
  case possible

  /// An desired cast is not possible.
  case impossible
}

public extension CastError {
  /// `nil` if  an `Instance` can be cast to `Desired`. Otherwise, `.impossible`.
  init?<Instance, Desired>(_: Instance, desired _: Desired.Type) {
    self.init(Instance.self, desired: Desired.self)
  }

  /// `nil` if  a `Source` can be cast to `Desired`. Otherwise, `.impossible`.
  init?<Source, Desired>(_: Source.Type, desired _: Desired.Type) {
    if Source.self is Desired.Type
    { return nil }

    self = .impossible
  }

  /// `nil` if  an `Instance` cannot be cast to `Undesired`. Otherwise, `.possible`.
  init?<Instance, Undesired>(_: Instance, undesired _: Undesired.Type) {
    self.init(Instance.self, undesired: Undesired.self)
  }

  /// `nil` if  a `Source` cannot be cast to `Undesired`. Otherwise, `.possible`.
  init?<Source, Undesired>(_: Source.Type, undesired _: Undesired.Type) {
    guard Source.self is Undesired.Type
    else { return nil }

    self = .possible
  }
}
```

You could wrap that, to conform to `Equatable`, with `Cast` being `Any`. Is there a use case?

```swift
/// A type-erased equatable value.
///
/// An `Equatable` instance is stored as a "`Cast`".
/// Only instances that can be cast to that type can be `==`'d with the `AnyEquatable`.
public struct AnyEquatable<Cast> {
  public init<Equatable: Swift.Equatable>(_ equatable: Equatable) throws {
    equals = try equatable.getEquals()
    cast = equatable as! Cast
  }

  private let equals: (Cast) -> Bool
  private let cast: Cast
}

extension AnyEquatable: Equatable {
  public static func == (equatable0: Self, equatable1: Self) -> Bool {
    equatable0 == equatable1.cast
  }
}

public extension AnyEquatable {
  static func == (equatable: Self, castable: Cast) -> Bool {
    equatable.equals(castable)
  }

  static func == (castable: Cast, equatable: Self) -> Bool {
    equatable.equals(castable)
  }
}
```

```swift
let anyEquatable = try AnyEquatable<Any>(cupcake)
XCTAssertEqual( anyEquatable, try .init(cupcake) )
XCTAssert(anyEquatable == cupcake)
XCTAssertFalse(notCake == anyEquatable)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn’t explain why not to use AnyHashable over a custom type erasure (possibly more specific) like AnyEquatable (or another flavor like your suggestion). Would you consider your suggestion simpler/better/easier than using AnyHashable? And still, why AnyEquatable is not part of the standard library?

Comment: I'm saying there's no use case; `getEquals` is probably more than needed. But show the use case if you have one! `AnyHashable` is what you use to erase `Hashable` things, because there are properties and methods associated with them. I'm saying it's not worth it to have a type, for what boils down to an operator. I think you're just looking at `AnyHashable` because it exists already, not because it wraps up almost as little as you actually want.

Comment: `AnyHashable` is also optimized by the compiler. It's slightly magical to avoid having to wrap it in a box. It primarily exists for NSDictionary to Dictionary bridging as far as I know. If you're finding you need AnyEquatable a lot or AnyHashable unrelated to bridging to Cocoa, you're probably misusing the type system IMO. Generally you should not make protocols require Equatable; you should add a custom `.isEqual` requirement if necessary. I discuss this around 37:44 here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXwJg0QTlZE